# How To Update Spyder 3.3.0

Tags: spyder

I currently use Spyder 3.2.8 with Anaconda/Miniconda.  When I open the Spyder editor, a Spyder update window pops up and shows Spyder 3.3.0 is available. It also indicates that "please wait until new conda packages are available and use conda to perform the update".

I followed the direction using anaconda prompt to update. My computer shows the packages were already installed successfully. However, my Spyder Editor is still the version 3.2.8 I also used Anaconda Navigator to update by clicking on the "gear" but no luck. How can I update from Spyder 3.2.8 to 3.3.0? Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 10):

The only thing which really did the trick is

```
conda install spyder=3.3.0
```

so in this case you have to explicitly provide the package version.

I have a clean anaconda 5.2.0 installation.

**Update:** after that i can "conda update spyder" and everything is consistent (for 3.3.1 and further versions)

Comment: Glad you figured it out at the end. Sorry for not being more helpful.

Comment: Hi Carlos, you were very helpful!! Its just looks like some unexpected behaviour specific for my case.

Comment: this is not working, it updates to 3.3 but i can not launch it at all. after restarting and doing `conda update --all` spyder reverts back to 2.8.

Answer (score 5):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) If you already tried to update (either through Navigator or in a system terminal) and you didn't get a new version, that means that conda packages are *still* unavailable and you have to wait a couple more days to perform the update.

Comment: Hi, Carlos! Almost a month later still the same thing. "conda update spyder", "conda install -c anaconda spyder" just says 3.2.8 is the latest ver. Updating from navigator show something like "updating spyder==3.3.0..." but nothing happens then. I guess its more anaconda`s issue but maybe you have some ino? Thank you!

Comment: Please loose the `-c anaconda`: `conda update spyder` should be enough.

Comment: Thank you, Carlos! But unfortunately it says that all packages are already installed, and doesnt offer to update 3.2.8 -> 3.3.0. Cant really get this bug. As i can see the package version on anacondas repo is 3.3.0...

Comment: What's your conda version?

Comment: conda --version gives "4.5.9". Looks like some package channels inconsistensy.

Answer (score 5):

You can get it from conda-forge:

```
conda install -c conda-forge spyder
```

Comment: Hi Peter, from my laptop (windows 10), I opened the Anaconda Prompt and entered the comment : "conda install -c conda-forge spyder".  After a short processing, a message popped up shows that: Solving environment : done; All required packages already installed. Then , I opened the Spyder thru the Anaconda Navigator and thru the Start, but it is still opened with the old version, the 3.2.8.  Did I update it appropriately? Could you please specify what you did?  And please assume I know zero about it? Thank you!

Comment: What I did was to verify that conda-forge had a 3.3.0 version available for the platform I was using (macos) by looking at the conda-forge page for [spyder](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/spyder), then I ran the install command as shown in the answer. That was it.
It may be that 3.2.8 is the latest available on conda-forge for your platform.

Comment: The comment: "conda install -c conda-forge spyder" is not worked for windows.  Does anyone know how to update the spyder 3.3.0 for windows, please share.  Thank you!

Comment: @BillLe, it won't work if you're using a 32 bits version of Windows.

Comment: Oh No!!!  I could upgrade the spyder package to 3.3.0 using the above command for my 64bit windows, but it seems it has degraded some important packages like "pyqt", "qt", "sqlite" and etc which has made Spyder unusable. I mean right now I am getting an error saying that the Python has stopped working when I want to launch Spyder!. So be careful with that guys!!!

Comment: Hi Carlos, I used windows 10 64 bits.  There is still no luck.  :-(

Comment: Hi Carlos, I was able to update my Spyder 3.3.0 , just today, 7/21.  I just went to the Anaconda Navigator > click on the 'gear' of the Spyder > Update application.  It worked the update perfectly.  Thanks!!!!!

Comment: On Windows 10: For conda install spyder=3.3.0 it never got past solving environment, after killing the batch job I did a conda update spyder which downloaded conda-4.6.7 (old 4.5.12). I then reopened Spyder and it still tells me 3.3.3 is available.

Comment: I then tried selecting Update Application from the Spyder cogwheel in Anaconda navigator it took about  5+ minutes. I launched Spyder from the start menu and it was v3.3.3.

Answer (score 3):

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/spyder
As you can see in that internet address, there is only 3.3.0 version for linux and osx.
I think that 3.3.0 version for window would be a little late.